# How to write an excel file which has dictionary keys as column name and dictionary values as column values?

Tags: python, django, excel, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows:

`[{'tarih': '01.02.2019', '4980': 1.1517482514, '2738': 0.9999999999999999, '0208': 1.0102518747365854},{'tarih': '02.02.2019', '4980': 1.1517486767, '2738': 0.9999999999999999, '0208': 1.0102518747368554}]`

I want ot write an excel file like:

```
tarih          4980           2738                   0208               // dictionary keys as column name
01.02.2019     1.1517482514   0.9999999999999999     1.0102518747365854 // dict values as value
02.02.2019     1.1517486767   0.9999999999999999     1.0102518747368554 // dict values as value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `pandas` module

```
import pandas as pd

x = [{'tarih': '01.02.2019', '4980': 1.1517482514, '2738': 0.9999999999999999, '0208': 1.0102518747365854},{'tarih': '02.02.2019', '4980': 1.1517486767, '2738': 0.9999999999999999, '0208': 1.0102518747368554}]

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

df.to_excel ('test.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1', index = False)
```

output:

```
     tarih      4980        2738    0208
0   01.02.2019  1.151748    1.0    1.010252
1   02.02.2019  1.151749    1.0    1.010252
```

Comment: Thanks @AkshayNevrekar. I used df.to_excel ('test.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1', index = False) together. I created the file I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open('dict.csv', 'w', newline="") as csv_file:  
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for key, value in mydict.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: That's going to write one *row* per entry with the key in the first column and the value in the second. What they're asking is for the keys as column headers and the values as row values. What csv.DictWriter does, basically.

Comment: @Masklinn yes you are right.  That's going to write one row per entry with the key in the first column and the value in the second. I want use dictionary keys as column name dictionary values as values.

Comment: I updated the question to better understand .@Masklinn and @Yeganeh Salami